# NavBrand image in navbar creates white spaces when changing the width in %

Tags: html, css

I want to add a logo to a nav bar using bootstrap, but the image is quite large to fit there. My solution is to add this into the CSS:

HTML

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                <img src="Fernando Borea - Logo.png" alt="" class="d-inline-block align-top headerLogo img-responsive">
            </a>
...
```

CSS

```
.headerLogo
{
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}
```

That works perfectly to reduce the image size, but I then get huge right margins:

[image]

However, when I change the CSS to be pixels, the huge margin goes away. I want to use % to easily change the size, but without getting the massive margin.

Using fixed values:

```
.headerLogo
{
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
```

[image]

I'm new to bootstrap/html/css/js so I'd really appreciate if you can explain why the solution works as well, thanks!:D

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out what was wrong. Adding img-fluid makes it to have the width equal to the original image width at all times. Removing img-fluid solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
.headerLogo {
  width: 100px
  max-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
```